# How to get original string prefix in boost regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, search, boost

I am using regex_search in boost like this:

```
std::string symbol = "abcd1234";

boost::regex regExpr("(\\d{4})", boost::regex::icase);

boost::smatch regMatch;

boost::regex_search(symbol, regMatch, regExpr);
```

What I need to get is: "abcd", i.e. the original string up to the first matched reg expression.
How is this possible?
thanks in advance...

Comment: Assuming the string is always followed by 4 digits: `(\\D*)\d{4}`

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
^(.*?)\\d{4}
```

**Explanation:**

`^` - the start of the string
`.` - wild-card
`.*?` - zero or more (`*`) wild-cards (`.`), matched non-greedily (`?`), so you get the first match, not the last one

So you match everything from the start of the string to the digits.

**Alternative using boost functionality:**

`regMatch.prefix()` should return the required string.

Comment: Feel free to click the check mark next to the answer to accept it, marking the question as answered.